# Regex how to select first instance of pattern in repeating pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string in which I need to find all instances of the following pattern:

```
{{.*Sm_.*}}
```

The problem I am having is this pattern repeats throughout the string, so when I try and do a non greedy match by doing:

```
{{.*Sm_.*?}}
```

It matches everything from the first to the last instance of this pattern, including a bunch of stuff that I don't want it to match. Essentially the string looks something like this:

```
{{.*Sm_.*}} Bunch of content {{.*Sm_.*}} More content {{.*Sm_.*}}
```

And that's repeating. I only want to capture the sections that match the pattern without capturing anything else.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following non greedy pattern will only target the `{{...}}` terms themselves, will spilling over across any content.

```regex
\{\{[^}]*Sm_.*?\}\}
```

### Demo

Comment: Ah, so *that's* what was meant in the OP...

Comment: @fireshadow52 Well I'm in the dark on this question about as much as you.  Typically, getting the "first" regex match would be a language-specific API thing, so the question title might be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

`.` and `*` are actual regex characters, so you'll need to escape them if you want the pattern to match. The pattern you want is this: `{{\.\*Sm_\.\*}}`

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question. Tim Biegeleisen has the right answer for your question.

Comment: I know. There is stuff between the curly brackets. The Sm_ is what identifies which content between curly brackets to get.

Comment: In that case, please post an actual (or at least representative) sample of your text under "the string looks something like this". The way your question reads, I might have answered similarly, too.